# Update Access Database With VB missing operator

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, oledb

I'm trying to update information in my database but apparently there's a missing operator. Can someone help me with that please?

```
Dim con As OleDbConnection
con = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= \\SERVER\RedirectedFolders\simono\Desktop\TechnoProjectManager\version 2.accdb")
Dim sql As String = "UPDATE SuiviPojet SET [NUMERO DE TC]='" & txtNumeroTC.Text & "' [STATUS]='" & status & "' [INGENIERIE]='" & ingenierie & "' [NOM DU PROJET ]='" & txtNomProjet.Text & "' [CLIENT FINAL]='" & txtClientFinal.Text & "' [CLIENT ACOMBA]='" & txtClientAcomba.Text & "' [DATE APPROBATION]='" & DTP_APPROBATION.Text & "' [DATE LIVRAISON]='" & DTP_LIVRAISON.Text & "' [NOTES]='" & RTB_NOTES.Text & "' WHERE [NUMERO DE TC]='" & txtNumeroTC.Text & "'"

con.Open()

Dim cmdUpdate As New OleDbCommand(sql, con)

cmdUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery()

con.Close()
```

Comment: You need commas between your set clauses, i.e. `[NUMERO DE TC]='" & txtNumeroTC.Text & "', [STATUS]=...`. Note that building a query as you are here is vulnerable to SQL injection. Use parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely in the SQL statement put the "sql" in a MsgBox and review all the single quotes and values are correct.